Border with Linear Gradient and Border Radius, and Background with Linear Gradient
I have a box with linear gradient border and linear gradient background. I also need it to have a border radius. This is what I have until now but the borders don't look good.


.demo-mode {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 62.72%) !important;
  background-origin: border-box !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100vw #111026;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 250px;
height: 250px;
padding: 40px;
}

.demo-mode .box {
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
  border-style: solid !important;
  border-width: 1px !important;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(
    91.7deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) 100%
  ) !important;
  background-origin: border-box !important;
  border-image-slice: 1 !important;
  background-image:  linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff0a, #ffffff03),
  linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff10, #ffffff03) !important;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box !important;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="demo-mode">
<div class="box">
Hello
</div>
</div>




remove border-image properties from .box, you don't need them

But I need a gradient for border also

that's what the background properties are already doing

But that is for background color what I need is different border linear-gradient and different background linear-gradient
